# How $~\lg 7 < n \leq \lg 7 + 1~$ can be satisfied?

Tags: logarithms, integers

$$\begin{align}
\lg&=\log_{10}\\
n&:=\text{number of the digits of}~7^{35}\\
35\lg 7&<n\in\mathbb N\\
35\lg 7&<n \underbrace{\leq 35\lg 7 +1}_{\text{what i want to prove} } 
\end{align}$$

At least I know that $~ \lg7 <1 ~$ is true, and I've been got stuck.

Can anyone give me some hint(s)?

Comment: Wait, i think i threw too an easy problem. I think that it is obvious that the inequality is true.

Comment: By calculator, you want $29.57\cdots<n\le30.57\cdots$ and the (integer) value of $n$ is obvious.  If you want to do it without a calculator, it might be a bit harder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you calculate $7^7$ by hand, you see that it is equal to $8.23\times 10^5$. This is strictly between $8\times 10^5$ and $10^6$.

Since $7^{35}=\left(7^7\right)^5$, we see that
$$7^{35}<10^{30}$$
We also have
$$7^{35}>8^5\times 10^{25}$$
Since $8^5=2^{15}=32\cdot 1024>3\times 10^4$, we have that $7^{35}>10^{29}$. Hence it has $30$ digits.

Answer (score 1):

In general, we could prove that if a positive integer $M$ has $n$ digits, then $\,\log_{10}M<n\leqslant\log_{10}M+1\,.$

**Proof :**

The smallest positive integer number which has $n$ digits is $10^{n-1}$, whereas the greatest one is $10^n-1$.

Consequently, since $M$ has $n$ digits, it follows that

$10^{n-1}\leqslant M\leqslant10^n-1<10^n\;\,,\;\;\,$ hence ,

$\log_{10}10^{n-1}\leqslant\log_{10}M<\log_{10}10^n\;\;,$

$n-1\leqslant\log_{10}M<n\;\;\,,\;\;\;$ which is equivalent to

$\log_{10}M<n\leqslant\log_{10}M+1\,.\\[10pt]$

---

In particular, if $M=7^{35}$, we get that

$\log_{10}7^{35}<n\leqslant\log_{10}7^{35}+1\;\;\,,\;\;\;$ that is ,

$35\log_{10}7<n\leqslant35\log_{10}7+1\;.$